# Using Git with multiple local locations

Tags: git, mamp, expressionengine, bitbucket, coda

I'll try to lay this out as best I can for clarity. Forgive me now if it gets too long...

I am using the following:

- Mac
- MAMP Pro
- Coda 2
- Locally connected server farm for hosting sitting behind firewall
- Git via Bitbucket using Coda source management and SourceTree (When needed)
- Developing ExpressionEngine 2 site with the following:

  - MSM - Multi Site Manager
  - Mountee - for mounting template files in EE like local drives on Mac

Locations are as follows:

**Local sites (Via MAMP Pro)**

- site_1
- site_2
- site_3
- site_4
- site_5

**Server (Live sites)**

- site_1
- site_2
- site_3
- site_4
- site_5

**Git (Using Bitbucket)**

My preferred workflow is as follows: Edit MAMP Pro (local) site in Coda 2 => Commit to BitBucket Repo from Coda 2 => Publish to live server in Coda 2

My issues begin with the live server being on the local network. Coda only allows **FTP**, **S3**, **SFTP**, and **WebDAV**. They don't support **SMB**, **NFS**, or **HTTPS**. Therefor I have set my dev machine to enable **Remote Login** so that I can connect to the "*remote*" server via my local dev machine by mounting the server and mapping the **SFTP** through the **localhost**. This works okay as long as I remember to connect to the various servers in the same order every day.

I ***CAN*** create mountee aliases of the mounted template locations for the "remote" live site locations that operate without the need to mount the server location prior to editing. (I think this works anyway)

Is there a way to establish just this mounted location alias as the remote location to publish to?

It pains me to say this, but I have the exact scenario setup on a Windows machine using Dreamweaver and it is operating flawlessly. I have the local site, remote site, and git commit, push, pull, etc. right there in the IDE. Moving over to the Mac side, I would like to get this same ease of workflow without the strain I am having thus far. It seems like this should be accomplished rather easily, but so far... eh.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I may not be understanding you correctly.

I don't understand the need for SFTP or FTP or any of that when you are using GIT? I'm not sure what Coda is doing when you "publish"… but you should log into your live server and pull from Bitbucket. Otherwise you're missing half the point of using GIT.

**In any case your live web server in your local network so you must still have an external facing IP you could SSH/SFTP into right?**

Hope that helps.

Comment: The reason I am using GIT is to keep revisionary changes and backups of various stages of development and also being able to branch out for various changes. When you "publish" in Coda, it just pushes whatever changes you have saved locally to the live server. Keeping it local on a local site allows for testing the changes without effecting the live site as of yet. I understand the usage of GIT, I just don't want to duplicate the work/entry process of those changes.

Comment: As for the last part, the answer is no. The internal IS department has all servers locked down from public access and keep very tight security. The admin for these sites is only accessible from within the local network when logged in. If you are not inside the building or VPN'd, you cannot access any backend elements. This is something they are not flexible on.    :(